# Не выводит содержимое $FIO

Tags: php, html, form

Извините, я первый раз тут выкладываю вопрос. Что-то вышло не то.

Звучало так:

Подскажите, где ошибка!? Не выводит содержимое $FIO

http://srcboard.com/76411072
http://srcboard.com/48r5m35h
http://srcboard.com/805tn21

Ошибок нет, ставил error_reporting(E_ALL);

Проблема исправлена дописал

```
<?if(isset($_POST['FIO'])):?>
Получено ФИО - <?=$_POST['FIO']?>
```

<?endif?>

Comment: приведите html код формы

Comment: @mkrichet, нет смысла перенаправлять куда-либо еще, когда есть возможность показать код прямо в теме. Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @mkrichet, внутри вашей функции не определена переменная $FIO, поэтому она и не выводится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `echo("$FIO");`

Где объявлена эта переменная?

> `slectTemplat($select)`

Правильно:  `selectTemplate($select)`

> `$fileContent = file_get_contents("$file");`
>
> `echo $fileContent;`

А если такого файла не будет?

> `$file = $select."T.txt";`
>
> `$fileContent = file_get_contents("$file");`

Можно просто пиcать `file_get_contents($file);` Без кавычек, так как в переменной `$file` лежит строка

UPD: ваш код после небольшого рефакторинга: [`patebin.com`](http://pastebin.com/GBy3p2va)

Comment: <input type="text" name="FIO" size="30px" maxlength="100"></form></br> 

FIO- есть, в php $FIO

Comment: файл http://srcboard.com/805tn21

Comment: > <input type="submit">

Замените на 

`<input type="submit" name="submit">`

Comment: изменил, ничего не изменилось

Comment: @mkrichet - ну, с таким "программерским" подходом мы далеко не уйдем. Пишет ли какие нибудь ошибки? Выводили ли вы массив $_POST на экран, что бы посмотреть, что к вам пришло? Какие-нибудь действия вы предпринимали, что бы устранить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Переменная $FIO не объявлена. Ваш КЭП.
Если она передаётся как POST то перед выводом сделайте присваивание

```
$FIO = $_POST['FIO'];
```

Comment: Я не верно оформил, вот переменная http://srcboard.com/805tn21